# 2D vertex of multiple countries

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, coordinate-system

[CodeChef - QPOINT](http://www.codechef.com/problems/QPOINT)

> Given a 2D vertex of multiple countries, find which country contains a certain point.
>
> Input format:
>
> ```
> "Number of countries"
> "Number of vertex" "x1" "y1" "x2" "y2" ...
> "Number of vertex" "x1" "y1" "x2" "y2" ...
> ...
> "Number of query"
> "x1" "y1"
> "x2" "y2"
> ...
> ```

Please give me any advise on code style or design patterns.

```cs
class QPOINT
{

    class Point
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;

        public Point()
        {
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        }

        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }


    class Line
    {
        public Point point1;
        public Point point2;

        public Line()
        {
            point1 = new Point();
            point2 = new Point();
        }

        public Line(Point point1, Point point2)
        {
            this.point1 = point1;
            this.point2 = point2;
        }
    }


    class CountryUnit
    {
        public List<Point> vertex = new List<Point>();
        public List<Line> boundaries = new List<Line>();
    }


    List<CountryUnit> CountryList = new List<CountryUnit>();



    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        QPOINT qpoint = new QPOINT();

        qpoint.ReadCountry();
        qpoint.ReadQueryAndPrintResult();
    }



    public void ReadCountry()
    {
        // First line is the total number of countries
        int countryCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Each following N lines contain all vertex of a single country
        for (int i = 0; i < countryCount; i++)
        {
            string[] vertexInfo = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            CountryList.Add(CreateNewCountry(vertexInfo));
        }
    }



    CountryUnit CreateNewCountry(string[] vertexInfo)
    {
        CountryUnit newCountry = new CountryUnit();

        // The first number is the total number of vertex
        int vertexCount = int.Parse(vertexInfo[0]);

        // The following numbers are N pairs of x,y coordinates
        for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
        {
            newCountry.vertex.Add(
                new Point(
                    int.Parse(vertexInfo[j * 2 + 1]),
                    int.Parse(vertexInfo[j * 2 + 2])
                )
            );
        }

        // Add the first coordinate to the list again to complete the circuit
        newCountry.vertex.Add(newCountry.vertex[0]);

        // Get boundaries of the country
        for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
        {
            newCountry.boundaries.Add(
                new Line(
                    newCountry.vertex[j],
                    newCountry.vertex[j + 1]
                )
            );
        }

        return newCountry;
    }



    public void ReadQueryAndPrintResult()
    {
        // Continuing line is the total number of queries
        int queryCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < queryCount; i++)
        {
            // Each following line is a query
            string[] pointInfo = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            Point thisQuery = new Point(
                int.Parse(pointInfo[0]),
                int.Parse(pointInfo[1])
            );

            // Output the result
            Console.WriteLine(GetContainingCountry(thisQuery));
        }
    }



    int GetContainingCountry(Point query)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CountryList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CountryContainsPoint(CountryList[i], query))
            {
                return (i + 1);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }



    bool CountryContainsPoint(CountryUnit country, Point query)
    {
        List<Line> boundaries = country.boundaries;

        // Create a line that extends towards x, starting from the query point
        Line infiniteLine = new Line(
            query, new Point(1000000, query.Y)
        );

        // Count the total times of intersection between the infinite line and boundaries
        int intersectCount = 0;

        foreach (Line boundary in boundaries)
        {
            // If the point is on the boundary, return true
            if (PointOnLine(query, boundary))
            {
                return true;
            }
            // Else, count intersections
            else if (TwoLinesIntersect(infiniteLine, boundary))
            {
                intersectCount++;
            }
        }

        // if total times of intersection is odd, return true
        if (intersectCount % 2 == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    bool PointOnLine(Point point, Line line)
    {
        Point a = point;
        Point c = line.point1;
        Point d = line.point2;

        if ((a.X - d.X) * (c.Y - d.Y) - (a.Y - d.Y) * (c.X - d.X) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }



    bool TwoLinesIntersect(Line line1, Line line2)
    {
        Point a = line1.point1;
        Point b = line1.point2;
        Point c = line2.point1;
        Point d = line2.point2;

        Point intersection = new Point();

        // lines are parallel
        if ((b.Y - a.Y) * (c.X - d.X) - (b.X - a.X) * (c.Y - d.Y) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        intersection.X = ((b.X - a.X) * (c.X - d.X) * (c.Y - a.Y) - c.X * (b.X - a.X) * (c.Y - d.Y) + a.X * (b.Y - a.Y) * (c.X - d.X)) / ((b.Y - a.Y) * (c.X - d.X) - (b.X - a.X) * (c.Y - d.Y));
        intersection.Y = ((b.Y - a.Y) * (c.Y - d.Y) * (c.X - a.X) - c.Y * (b.Y - a.Y) * (c.X - d.X) + a.Y * (b.X - a.X) * (c.Y - d.Y)) / ((b.X - a.X) * (c.Y - d.Y) - (b.Y - a.Y) * (c.X - d.X));

        if ((intersection.X - a.X) * (intersection.X - b.X) <= 0 && (intersection.X - c.X) * (intersection.X - d.X) <= 0 && (intersection.Y - a.Y) * (intersection.Y - b.Y) <= 0 && (intersection.Y - c.Y) * (intersection.Y - d.Y) <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Please give me any advise on code style or design-pattern

Comment: Please make sure to include a language tag in the future. Welcome to CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like that you defined some classes to help solve the problem, but your `Point` and `Line` have a pretty glaring issues. They're *mutable*.

> ```
>     class Point
>     {
>         public double X;
>         public double Y;
> ```

In my mind, you shouldn't be able to change a point or a line after it's been created. That's because if you change it, it is effectively a *different* point. I would only allow the coordinates to be set via the constructor and change these from public fields to get-only properties. You should also consider whether or not a struct would be sufficient for your needs.

I would also chain your constructors so that the parameter less one calls the other.

```
    class Point
    {
        public double X { get; private set; }
        public double Y { get; private set; }

        public Point()
            :this(0,0) { }

        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
```

The second issue I see here is that your implementation is bound to the console. Many of your methods should be taking in arguments instead of directly getting input from the user. There should be another class solely responsible for interacting with the user. Main should be responsible for passing information to/from that class to/from the one that is calculating the solution. This will make it easier to use your class anywhere and put it under test.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick remarks:

- Don't make class names all caps.
- State your [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) explicitly.
- `public double X;`: This is intended as a property and thus should have a getter/setter.
- `public Point point1;`: This is intended as a property and thus should have a getter/setter. It [should also be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).
- `public List<Point> vertex = new List<Point>();`: vertex is a single item, the plural is vertices. Also, this is intended as a property and thus should have a getter/setter. It [should also be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).
- `class Point`, `class Line`, `class CountryUnit` should IMHO not be subclasses of `class QPOINT`, but should be classes of their own (and separate files).
- Why do `for (int i = 0; i < countryCount; i++)` when you can simply use a `foreach` to loop through the result of `Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')`?
- Your code assumes the input is always in the correct format. You shouldn't anticipate that, and you should check that the received input is in the correct format.
- `Point a`, `Point b`, `Point c`, `Point d`: these are meaningless names.
- Many of your comments are not necessary, e.g. `Else, count intersections`.
- Your code contains far too many blank lines between methods.
- `GetContainingCountry()` returns an int?
- Why assign `List<Line> boundaries = country.boundaries;`? Why not simply use `country.boundaries`?